# iOS Objective-C didReceiveRemoteNotification not triggered when app is closed or swipe out

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented Firebase in my iOS app and use data-only payload. So far my custom notification works fine when the app is open or minimized. But when I swipe the app, I am no longer receiving any remote messages any more. When you swipe the app I am not sure if the app is suspended or not running.

So far I did something like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   NSDictionary *userInfo = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
   CustomNotif *notif = [[CustomNotif alloc] init];

   [notif showNotification:userInfo];
}
```

CustomNotif is a class I created to handle my notification UI. I already set the aps payload to:

**priority: 'high'** and **content-available: 1**

and this is what I get when remote message is being received:

```
{
  aps =     {
        "content-available" = 1;
    };
    body = "sample body";
    "gcm.message_id" = "0:1538531666855542%d0cc52a4d0cc52a4";
    iconURL = "http://www.shutterangle.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/bladerunner.jpg";
    title = "Urgent action needed!";
}
```

I only get that payload when app is open or minimized. Is there a way to get it when I swipe the app or close it?

---

I would like to add more info . . I tried closing the app and look at the device log in xcode and found out that even the app is totally closed, when someone send a remote notification, the app is still triggered; however, I just don't know how to get the data.

Here is the log that shows everytime someone send a notification:

```
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd(CommonUtilities)[112] <Notice>: Created power assertion {identifier: APSCourier(tcpStream:dataReceived:)}
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd[112] <Notice>: <private>: Outstanding data received: <private> (length 477) onInterface: NonCellular. Connected on 1 interfaces.
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd[112] <Notice>: <private>: Stream processing: complete yes, invalid no, length parsed 473, parameters <private>
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd(CommonUtilities)[112] <Notice>: Created power assertion {identifier: APSCourier(tcpStream:dataReceived:)}
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd[112] <Notice>: copyTokenForDomain sandbox.push.apple.com (null)
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd[112] <Notice>: <private> incoming message is for proxy slave that is *not* connected. baseToken <private>  destToken <private>  publicTokens <private>
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd[112] <Notice>: <private> timestampForTopic? <private> token <private>
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd[112] <Notice>: isAppSpecificTokenValid sandbox.push.apple.com <private>
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd[112] <Notice>: isAppSpecificTokenValid? <private> found cached token YES
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd[112] <Notice>: <private> hasPayload? <private> forTopic <private> tokens <private>
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd[112] <Notice>: copyAppSpecificTokensWithDomain - sandbox.push.apple.com for topic <private> account <private>
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd[112] <Notice>: <private> receivedPushWithTopic <private> token <private> payload <private> timestamp Thu Oct  4 14:21:57 2018
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd[112] <Notice>: <private>: Received message for enabled topic '<private>' onInterface: NonCellular with payload '<private>' with priority 5 for device token: NO
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd[112] <Notice>: <private> asked to store incoming message <private> with guid <private> environment <private>
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd[112] <Notice>: <private>: Calling into AWD for PushReceived
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd[112] <Notice>: submitted metric <private>
Oct  4 14:21:57 analyticsd[90] <Notice>: [<private>] no observers; dropped.
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd[112] <Notice>: <private> deleting low-priority incoming messages for topic <private> environment development
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd[112] <Notice>: APSMessageStore - APSIncomingMessageRecordDeleteMessagesForTopic <private> 1 environment development
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd[112] <Notice>: APSMessageStore - New message record [<private>] has ID [6954].
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd[112] <Notice>: <private>: AWD for PushReceived finished
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd[112] <Notice>: <private>: Stream processing: complete yes, invalid no, length parsed 4, parameters <private>
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd[112] <Notice>: <private>: Received keep-alive response 1 on interface NonCellular: <private>
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd(CommonUtilities)[112] <Notice>: Releasing power assertion {identifier: APSCourier(tcpStream:dataReceived:)}
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd(CommonUtilities)[112] <Notice>: Created power assertion {identifier: APSCourier(tcpStream:dataReceived:)}
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd[112] <Notice>: <private>: Stream processing: complete no, invalid no, length parsed 0, parameters (null)
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd[112] <Notice>: <private> calling completion block for incoming message <private>
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd[112] <Notice>: <private>: Sending acknowledgement message with response 0 and messageId <private> (1505639937)
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd[112] <Notice>: <private> Noting push - using last lq 0 and rat (null)  (instead of -2, kCTRegistrationRadioAccessTechnologyUTRAN)
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd[112] <Notice>: <private>:APSNetworkMonitor decaying cost (1498 - 4) = 1494 for 14.404547 seconds
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd[112] <Notice>: <private>:APSNetworkMonitor addCost: 166 - _currentCost is now 1500
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd[112] <Notice>: <private> _notifyForIncomingMessage <private> with guid <private>
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd[112] <Notice>: Dispatching low priority message: <xpc object>
Oct  4 14:21:57 SpringBoard(ApplePushService)[55] <Notice>: <private> Delivering message from apsd: <private> 1505639937 <private>
Oct  4 14:21:57 SpringBoard(ApplePushService)[55] <Notice>: <private> making delegate (<private>) calls to deliver message 1505639937 <private> for topic <private>
Oct  4 14:21:57 SpringBoard(ApplePushService)[55] <Notice>: <private> calling <private> connection:didReceiveIncomingMessage:
Oct  4 14:21:57 SpringBoard(ApplePushService)[55] <Notice>: <private> returned from <private> connection:didReceiveIncomingMessage:
Oct  4 14:21:57 SpringBoard(ApplePushService)[55] <Notice>: <private> responding with an ack for message with guid <private>
Oct  4 14:21:57 SpringBoard(UserNotificationsServer)[55] <Notice>: Received incoming message on topic com.rometic.trulyrussiandev at priority 1
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd[112] <Notice>: Looking up connection on peer: 5171ff0   found <private>
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd[112] <Notice>: <private> informed that <private> acknowledges incoming message with guid <private>
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd[112] <Notice>: <private> Removing incoming message with guid <private>
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd[112] <Notice>: <private> _schedulePendingWorkUpdate
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd[112] <Notice>: APSMessageStore - APSIncomingMessageRecordDeleteMessageForGUID <private>
Oct  4 14:21:57 SpringBoard(UserNotificationsServer)[55] <Notice>: [com.rometic.trulyrussiandev] Received remote notification request 135F-D297 [ hasAlertContent: 0, hasSound: 0 hasBadge: 0 hasContentAvailable: 1 hasMutableContent: 0 ]
Oct  4 14:21:57 SpringBoard(UserNotificationsServer)[55] <Notice>: [com.rometic.trulyrussiandev] Deliver push notification request 135F-D297
Oct  4 14:21:57 SpringBoard(UserNotificationsServer)[55] <Notice>: [com.rometic.trulyrussiandev] Passing content-available push to Duet
Oct  4 14:21:57 SpringBoard(DuetActivityScheduler)[55] <Notice>: SUBMITTING: <private>
Oct  4 14:21:57 SpringBoard(UserNotificationsServer)[55] <Error>: Ignoring notification with no alert, sound or badge (com.rometic.trulyrussiandev): 135F-D297
Oct  4 14:21:57 SpringBoard(UserNotificationsServer)[55] <Notice>: [com.rometic.trulyrussiandev] Not saving push notification 135F-D297 to store [ error=Error Domain=UNErrorDomain Code=1401 "Notification has no user-facing content" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Notification has no user-facing content} ]
Oct  4 14:21:57 dasd(DuetActivitySchedulerDaemon)[153] <Notice>: Submitted Activity: com.apple.pushLaunch.com.rometic.trulyrussiandev:DD5321 <private>
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd[112] <Notice>: Created metric container: 0x130004 succeeded? YES
Oct  4 14:21:57 dasd(DuetActivitySchedulerDaemon)[153] <Notice>: Daemon Canceling Activities: {(
    com.apple.pushLaunch.com.rometic.trulyrussiandev:DD5321
)}
Oct  4 14:21:57 dasd(DuetActivitySchedulerDaemon)[153] <Notice>: CANCELED: com.apple.pushLaunch.com.rometic.trulyrussiandev:DD5321 <private>!
Oct  4 14:21:57 dasd(DuetActivitySchedulerDaemon)[153] <Notice>: Removing a launch request for application <private> by activity <private>
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd[112] <Notice>: Submitted metric: 0x130004 succeeded? YES
Oct  4 14:21:57 apsd(WirelessDiagnostics)[112] <Notice>: client.trigger:#N Random sample for 0x130004 is skip
Oct  4 14:21:57 SpringBoard(DuetActivityScheduler)[55] <Notice>: cancelActivities: 1 activities were not found: <private>
Oct  4 14:21:57 analyticsd[90] <Notice>: [<private>] no observers; dropped.
Oct  4 14:21:57 rtcreportingd[224] <Notice>: releaseXPCTransactions: XPC transaction ref count is 0, decremented by 1
Oct  4 14:21:57 rtcreportingd[224] <Notice>: releaseXPCTransactions: XPC transaction ended
Oct  4 14:21:57 symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator)[122] <Notice>: L2 Metrics on ifname en0: rssi: -56 (txFrames/txReTx/txFail) 4/2/0 -> (was/is) 0/0
Oct  4 14:21:57 sharingd(WirelessProximity)[61] <Notice>: Nearby stop advertising of type: 16
Oct  4 14:21:57 sharingd(WirelessProximity)[61] <Notice>: Nearby start advertising with data: Advertising request of type 16, priority 1, UseFG 432 (270.00 ms), data <0b10dfe0 72>, connectable 1, options {
} priority 0 mode 432 options (null)
Oct  4 14:21:57 wirelessproxd[59] <Notice>: Stop advertising for process sharingd (61) of type 16
Oct  4 14:21:57 wirelessproxd[59] <Notice>: Nothing left to advertise, stopping
Oct  4 14:21:57 wirelessproxd[59] <Notice>: Start advertising for process sharingd (61) of type 16 with advertising interval 432 (270.00 ms)
Oct  4 14:21:57 wirelessproxd[59] <Notice>: Adding data of type: 16, advData: <0b10dfe0 72> advInterval: 432
Oct  4 14:21:57 wirelessproxd[59] <Notice>: Current advertisement packet: <10050b10 dfe072>
Oct  4 14:21:57 bluetoothd[79] <Notice>: Received XPC message "CBMsgIdStopAdvertising" from session "com.apple.wirelessproxd-peripheral-59-2"
Oct  4 14:21:57 bluetoothd[79] <Notice>: Received 'stop advertising' request from session "com.apple.wirelessproxd-peripheral-59-2"
Oct  4 14:21:57 bluetoothd[79] <Notice>: Sending XPC message "CBMsgIdAdvertisingStopped" to session "com.apple.wirelessproxd-peripheral-59-2"
Oct  4 14:21:57 bluetoothd[79] <Notice>: Received XPC message "CBMsgIdStopAdvertising" from session "com.apple.wirelessproxd-peripheral-59-3"
Oct  4 14:21:57 bluetoothd[79] <Notice>: Sending XPC message "CBMsgIdAdvertisingStopped" to session "com.apple.wirelessproxd-peripheral-59-3"
Oct  4 14:21:57 bluetoothd[79] <Notice>: Sending 'advertising status changed' event to local device listeners
Oct  4 14:21:57 wirelessproxd[59] <Notice>: AdvertisingRulesiOS: current advertisers: <NSMutableIndexSet: 0x119e0c490>[number of indexes: 1 (in 1 ranges), indexes: (16)]
Oct  4 14:21:57 wirelessproxd[59] <Notice>: advertisingRulesiOS - advertising packets: (
        {
        kCBAdvDataAppleMfgData = <0aff4c00 10050b10 dfe072>;
        kCBAdvDataIsConnectable = 1;
        kCBAdvOptionAdvertisingInterval = 432;
        kCBMsgArgIsPrivilegedDaemon = 1;
    }
)
Oct  4 14:21:57 wirelessproxd[59] <Notice>: Requesting to start advertising for clients 16  with (
        {
        kCBAdvDataAppleMfgData = <0aff4c00 10050b10 dfe072>;
        kCBAdvDataIsConnectable = 1;
        kCBAdvOptionAdvertisingInterval = 432;
        kCBMsgArgIsPrivilegedDaemon = 1;
    }
)
```

The log show the remote message is being processed in the background but I don't know why it can not hit the notification. I noticed this being called **"connection:didReceiveIncomingMessage"**.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be handling push notifications in the below method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo 
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler;
```

This method is used to process incoming notifs. It is called when your app is running in the foreground or background. And if you have the remote notifications background mode enabled, the system will launch your app and puts it in background state to handle the notif (note - it will NOT relaunch the app if the user has force-quit the app).

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, yes I already have that method added and it handles the remote notification when the is open or minimized. But when I close the app, `didReceiveRemoteNotification` will no longer work.

Some posts here said that if app is suspended or closed, you can handle it in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method which I am not sure how since I am new to Objective-C.

Comment: it is okay if the app will not relaunch . . I just want to see the notification coming in even if the app is closed.